# Are second-order phase transitions always scale/Lorentz invariant?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, conformal-field-theory, phase-transition

I know that both scale invariance and Lorentz invariance typically emerge at second-order phase transitions, but is there a proof or a counterexample?  (I know that it's believed that any theory that is both scale- and Lorentz-invariant must also be conformally invariant, and that Joe Polchinski has proven this to be true in two dimensions, but that's not my question.)  In fact, have *any* of the many qualitative differences between first- and second-order phase transitions been proven to hold in general?  (I'm defining the order of a phase transition to be the lowest discontinuous derivative of the thermodynamic-limit free energy density.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that second-order phase transitions are characterized by scale invariance but *not* necessarily Lorentz invariance.  For example, any critical point whose low-lying excitation spectrum is quadratic in momentum rather than linear will be scale invariant, but neither Lorentz nor conformal symmetry will emerge at the phase transition.  Examples of phase transitions that are scale-invariant but not conformal are free fermions with the chemical potential tuned to the metal-band-insulator transition and Heisenberg antiferromagnets at the saturation applied field.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by Lorentz-invariance? The "Lorentz-invariance" which is a part of the conformal group which people talk about in phase transitions is simply the rotations, isn't it?

Comment: @PeterKravchuk No, it's also the boosts, with the speed of light replaced by the speed of sound.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting and not what I am used to think about. Do you have any references to situations when Lorentz-invariance emerges? I am a bit puzzled, because in equilibrium thermodynamic descriptions, time is either not a part of the description or is periodic and imaginary. Are you referring to some non-equilibrium properties (in the sense in which sound is not equilibrium)?

Comment: @PeterKravchuk There are two different contexts in which a Lorentz-like symmetry can emerge.  In statistical field theory, as you say the time coordinate is imaginary, so in systems like the $\varphi^4$ scalar field theory that describes the Ising model, the emergent symmetry group is $SO(4)$.  But independently of equilibrium statistical field theory, you can also consider the real-time dynamics of the excitations about the ground state.  (You can do this for any system, e.g. lattice systems, not just field theories.)  If the excitations have a linear dispersion of the form ...

Comment: ... $\omega = c_s k$ for small $k$, then the dynamics of the long-wavelength excitations will show true $SO(3,1)$ Lorentz invariance, with a "speed of light" given by the speed of sound $c_S$.  This happens all the time in, e.g., systems that spontaneously break a continuous symmetry, like acoustic phonons in a superfluid or spin waves in an antiferromagnet.  See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63507/how-to-understand-the-emergent-special-relativity-in-the-superfluid for further discussion.

Comment: I do not think I agree that in Ising model there is an SO(4) symmetry at phase transition (I know some stuff about Ising CFT in 3d). Well, sure, the conformal group $SO(4,1)$ does have such a subgroup, but it isn't the one that we are talking about, since it is of conformal nature (the new generators here are combinations of the form $K_\mu+P_\mu$). So I am skeptical about the first part of your comment. The second part of your comment is what I expected, so I agree with you here. These are symmetries of the dynamics. ...

Comment: ... The dynamical theory has to be unitary, and then (modulo some technical assumptions) it is believed that scale invariance implies conformal invariance (is this what you meant in the parenthesis in your question?). Note that the Euclidean equivalent of unitarity for statistical theories is reflection positivity, and it is not fundamentally required (this is why there are non-unitary CFT's we care about in statistical mechanics).

Comment: I meant the implication under the hypothesis of Lorentz-invariance of your dynamical theory (Poincare, to be pedantic).  The point I was making was that the theories you are talking about are always unitarity as in "because conservation of probability", while the Euclidean statistical theories are not always unitary, because for them unitarity is reflection positivity and is not fundamentally required. This is important because unitarity is crucial for present understanding of scale $\to$ conformal.

Comment: Regarding Ising model, 3d Ising model (i.e. which aims to describe the magnet I hold in my hand) does not have any $SO(4)$ symmetry. It only has $SO(3)$, and the same is true for the $\phi^4$ theory a 3-dimensional Wilson-Fisher fixed point of which is the same as Ising CFT. Perhaps it is just the wording we are arguing about. I can imagine that there is a Lorentz-invariant 3+1-dimensional field theory which, being put at an appropriate temperature, flows in the IR to the Ising CFT. But still, the thing we call 3d Ising CFT does not have a non-conformal $SO(4)$.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Sorry, you're absolutely right about the Ising model - I was thinking of the Quantum Transverse Ising Model and I completely forgot to specify that.